# Relation between LimitRange's default, defaultRequest, max and min limits

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I do not understand kubernetes `LimitRange` configuration.
I created a manifest with following contents:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: cpu-limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      cpu: 4
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: 4
    max:
      cpu: 6

    type: Container
```

And then I run following commands :

```
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl  delete  pods default-cpu-demo-19 1^C
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl  get pods  -n=limit
NAME                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default-cpu-demo-19   0/1     Pending   0          9s
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl  describe pods   -n=limit
......(omitted unnecessary echo here)......
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  14s (x8 over 9m2s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu.
```

Of course, I know that  most amount of *limit:cpu* of a container can not be more bigger than that of above configuration. Otherwise, kubernets will report insufficient cpu.

And yet most amount of *max:cpu* of a container can not be bigger than that of above configuration as well.

I can't distinguish between maximum and limit, because a value is bigger than the limit or max is not allowed.

So, I want to know what they represent respectively and relation among them.

Comment: Can you give an example of a configuration and the context where you might see it?  (Kubernetes has resource constraints, but not using the terminology you're describing here.)

Comment: I updated my description.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, what you asked is -- what's the difference between min, max, default and defaultRequest limits for containers set in `LimitRange` resource. The answer is very simple:

- defaultRequest — is how much CPU/Memory will be given to Container, if it doesn't specify it's own value
- default — is **default limit** for amount of CPU/Memory for Container, if it doesn't specify it's own value
- max — is maximum limit for amount of CPU/Memory that Container can ask for. I.e. it **can't set it's own limit more than that**
- min — is minimum limit amount of CPU/Memory that Container can ask for. I.e. it **can't set it's own limit less than that**

[Here is](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-constraint-namespace/) part of official documentation that has examples and more info on that topic.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have clearly understood the problem with your help and my test.